# How can I get the PK of the Max Row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL Query which gets the Order with the Most Items. I did it like this:

```
select max(ab.num) as anzahl 
     from ( select auf.anr as anr,count(*) as num from
        Auftrag auf, Table(auf.positionen) po group by auf.anr  ) ab ;
```

My result look like this:

[image]

I want to know how to get the Order-ID [auf.anr] of this Order. How can I modify my query to get the desired Result?

This is the Order Table (Auftrag):

[image]

Comment: what is `Table(auf.positionen)` ? That doesnt look right

Comment: that is an an Array of Order Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the `row_number` analytic function:

```
with cte as (
  select auf.anr as anr,
         count(*) as num
    from Auftrag auf, Table(auf.positionen) po
   group by auf.anr
)
select anr
  from (select anr,
               row_number() over (order by num desc) as rn
          from cte)
 where rn = 1
```

... or, using the method that Juan Carlos was proposing (using `rownum`), this would be the syntax:

```
with cte as (
  select auf.anr as anr,
         count(*) as num
    from Auftrag auf, Table(auf.positionen) po
   group by auf.anr
)
select anr
  from (select *
          from cte
         order by num desc)
 where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you thats Work!! great!. can you please explain why did you do it like This=

Comment: I think the german code block my brain and forgot the `row_number()`.  But I think OP should consider `RANK()` in case some ties are possible

Comment: You should have to do some reading oracle can explain it before than us [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)  and  [RANK()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm)